# how to convert wchar_t to string in swift

Tags: c, swift

I'd like to get a `wchar_t` array from `C` library, and convert it to swift data structure, my code is here:

```
    func getResults(recognizer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, stroke: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>, touchState: Int32) -> [String] {
    var bufLen : Int32
    var buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<wchar_t>.alloc(Int(bufLen))        
    getRecognition(recognizer, stroke, touchState, buf, bufLen)

    var results = String.fromCString(buf)! //this line has an error, cause the buf is wchar_t*, not char*
}
```

how could I convert buf to swift data structure?
I know if buf is `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(Int(bufLen))`, we can use `String.fromCString(buf)`! to convert it.

If I println(buf[0]), it's print an integer 67, which is the ascii value of 'C', how can I println(buf[0]) as 'C' instead of 0? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wchar_t` is an alias for `Int32` and contains a UTF-32 code point
in host byte order (which is little-endian on all current iOS and OS X
platforms).

Therefore you can convert the buffer to a Swift string as follows:

```
if let str = NSString(bytes: UnsafePointer(buf),
    length: wcslen(buf) * sizeof(wchar_t),
    encoding: NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding) as? String {
        println(str)
} else {
    // encoding problem ...
}
```

(This assumes that the `wchar_t` string from the C library function
is zero-terminated.)

Comment: You certainly know your `wchar_t`s

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var char = Character(UnicodeScalar(Int(buf[idx])))
```

can interpret wchar_t to Character